# Should I always minimize IO in my App

Tags: c#, disk-io

I have a c# desktop app.

It 'reads' from 4 digital cameras 1 JPEG frame at a time.

Each JPEG is no more than 20K bytes.
For every motion movement detected I save the frame to my hard drive.

The other way to store my footage is to create AVI files in my managed code and say split it up after a certain size has built up.

The reason I save 1 JPEG at a time is that if a burglar steals my PC with the app running or/and the PC reboots itself or/and the app just stops then I would always be able to save the latest frame.

If I took the AVI approach I would lose whatever cut-off I had set in my code.

I know that if a burglar stole  my PC they would also have all my footage but I could circumvent that by saving to an external hard drive stored in a safe (for example).

So, bearing in mind the low number of bytes to save (but possibly frequent) is this the best  I can hope to achieve in terms of memory efficiency?

thanks

Comment: Depends on the FPS. How many frames do you save per second? Also in most case you can detect when a system shutdown is about to happen so this is not really an issue.

Comment: @Kryptos Thanks for your comment. The FPS as I mentioned in the question is determined by the amount of motion there is. However, there is an upper limit of 10FPS.  It still is an issue if the equipment is stolen. The burglar is unlikely to shut down Windows in the proper way. They are more likley to rip the power plug out of the socket

Comment: @closer why is the question too broad?  I thought it was quite specific? Please explain your reasoning so I can amend

Comment: @2nd Clser. You too did not explain why? I think it is a straight forward question as least explain why it is not?  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider different aspects of the problem.

**Writing rate**

Your maximum writing rate would be 800KB/s (10 FPS, 4 camera, 20KB for each frame) which is not very high on modern HDD (even for external hard drive). It is even less of importance if you are using a SSD.

**How to improve writing efficiency**

Traditionally, writing efficiency is improved by caching data into buffer and writing big chuncks of data when the buffer reach a certain size. In your case, I think this will be a bad idea to write your own buffer mechanism.

1. Most operating system already have some kind of caching mechanism to prevent disk thrashing and fragmentation of data.
2. You want to have the latest frame possible written to the disk, i.e. prevent loss of data. Caching does the contrary since its delay the writing and the whole buffer could be lost in case of a failure (e.g. in your case if someone unplug the device).

That's why I think that you should keep your implementation the simplest possible (think KISS). You might even consider disabling the operating system caching. This might cause more fragmentation of data but you will ensure to have the most recent frame written on the disk. (Note that in case of a SSD, the fragmentation issue is irrelevant.)

Comment: very good - thanks.  You have given me info that was new to me. I will take your recommendations on board and research them. thanks